# I want to concatenate the values of both array from json file and convert in to string

Tags: angular6

I have 2 combo box which has data from json file, i want to concatenate the value of combo1 and combo2. both combo box data comes from different json files.
i am new on angular and in learning phase.

If you have to go through a code file please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: yes please add exmaple code and example json and preferably how youve  tried it before

Comment: hi jonathan, thanks for your comment but i solved this problem. really appreciated for your comment. but now i face another problem so i post another question if you help me i am very glad to you.